# Is there a way to combine XML files and mapping by code in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have been using the NHibernate mapping by code feature in NHibernate >= 3.2 and quite like it. Now I would like to start using it in an existing project where we have approximately 80 `*.hbm.xml` files. It is not feasible to change all of the `*.hbm.xml` files in one go, so I would like to use mapping by code for new mappings, and gradually convert the existing XML files over time.

I tried converting one XML file to mapping by code and modified my configuration building code to introduce mapping by code. Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
private void AddMappings(Configuration configuration, Assembly assembly)
{
    // add mappings from embedded *.hbm.xml files
    configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);

    // add mappings from map by code
    var modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.AddMappings(assembly.GetExportedTypes());
    var mapping = modelMapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
    configuration.AddMapping(mapping);
}
```

What I find is that the entities in the XML files are added to the configuration, but my mapping by code class is not added.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you comment `configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);` dows it even add the MbC classes?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to do what you wish:

```
    private IHibernateConfigurationExtension m_ExtensionConfig;
    private Configuration m_Configuration;
    public Configuration Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_Configuration == null)
            {
                m_ExtensionConfig = FetchExtensionConfig();
                m_Configuration = new Configuration();
                string assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(m_ExtensionConfig.Assembly.Location);
                m_Configuration.Configure(Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"));
                m_Configuration = LoadHBMXML(m_Configuration);
                m_Configuration = LoadMappings(m_Configuration);
            }
            return m_Configuration;
        }
    }


    #region NHibernate Configuration
    /// <summary>
    /// Load the assemblies that are configured with the *.hbm.xml configuration
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Configuration LoadHBMXML(Configuration configuration)
    {
        configuration.AddAssembly(m_ExtensionConfig.Assembly);
        return configuration;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load the configurations that are configured with the ClassMap convention (NHibernate 3.2+)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Configuration LoadMappings(Configuration configuration)
    {
        // This configuration for mapper files
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.BeforeMapProperty += new PropertyMappingHandler(mapper_BeforeMapProperty);
        List<Type> typeList = m_ExtensionConfig.Assembly.GetMatchingTypesInAssembly(item => m_ExtensionConfig.MappingsNamespace.Equals(item.Namespace)).ToList();
        mapper.AddMappings(typeList);
        IEnumerable<HbmMapping> mappings = mapper.CompileMappingForEachExplicitlyAddedEntity();
        mappings.ForEach(m => configuration.AddMapping(m));
        if (DumpToXML)
            mappings.WriteAllXmlMapping();
        return configuration;
    }
```

The interface I use

```
/// <summary>
/// An interface to be implemented within the assembly using the 
/// HibernateDAO class.  This determines what gets configured
/// for hibernate automatically.
/// <para>NOTE: Currently only supports a single implementation
/// within all loaded assemblies</para>
/// </summary>
public interface IHibernateConfigurationExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The namespace containing the mapping files.
    /// <para>Only a single namespace is currently supported</para>
    /// </summary>
    string MappingsNamespace { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The assembly to search for .hbm.xml hibernate configuration files
    /// </summary>
    Assembly Assembly { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary of conversion mappings
    /// <para>Type is the object type, the type used in object definitions</para>
    /// <para>Type of IUserType is the NHIbernate IUserType implementation to convert 
    /// between the Type and the persisted representation</para>
    /// </summary>
    IDictionary<Type, Type> UserConversionMappings { get; }
}
```

And the method to fetch the extension config

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Fetch the class that implements the IHibernateConfigurationExtension interface
    /// <para>Support is only provided for a single implementation of this class
    /// through all loaded assemblies</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The class that implements the extension</returns>
    private IHibernateConfigurationExtension FetchExtensionConfig()
    {
        ICollection<Type> interfaces = AssemblyUtils.GetMatchingTypes(item => item.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IHibernateConfigurationExtension)));
        if (interfaces.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("No implementation of IHibernateConfigurationExtension found");
        if (interfaces.Count > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Only support for a single implementation if IHibernateConfigurationExtension available.  Please raise support request");
        return Activator.CreateInstance(interfaces.First()) as IHibernateConfigurationExtension;
    }
```

And the piece out of AssemblyUtils that is required

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all matching types in all assemblies that match the predicate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">The predicate function to match the types against</param>
    /// <returns>The list of all types that match the predicate</returns>
    public static ICollection<Type> GetMatchingTypes(Predicate<Type> predicate)
    {
        ICollection<Type> types = new List<Type>();
        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            try
            {
                types.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes().Where(i => i != null && predicate(i)).ToList());
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
            {
                types.AddRange(ProcessExceptionTypes(ex.Types, i => i != null && predicate(i)));
            }
        }
        return types;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Process each of the types in the list (usually called from within a ReflectionTypeLoadException
    /// to load the types that match the predicate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="theTypes">The list of types to process (taken from ReflectionTypeLoadException.Types</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">The boolean predicate to compare the type against</param>
    /// <returns>The collection of types (that can be loaded) matching the predicate</returns>
    private static ICollection<Type> ProcessExceptionTypes(Type[] theTypes, Predicate<Type> predicate)
    {
        ICollection<Type> types = new List<Type>();
        foreach (Type theType in theTypes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (predicate(theType))
                    types.Add(theType);
            }
            // This exception list is not exhaustive, modify to suit any reasons
            // you find for failure to parse a single assembly
            catch (BadImageFormatException)
            {
                // Type not in this assembly - reference to elsewhere ignored
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                // Type not in this assembly - reference to elsewhere ignored
            }
        }
        return types;
    }
```

Comment: It´s missing what is the FetchExtensionConfig() and the m_ExtensionConfig